# Node.js/Javascript Multidimensional Array with dynamic Key

Tags: javascript, node.js

I request some data from my database which returns me an Value which is the Type of an int.

```
var id = databaseReturn["id"]; //-> int 2
```

Now when I try to make an Array with and key of that value it doesnt work because it is an int, but even after converting it to a String it doesnt work.

```
id = String(id); //Should be -> String "2"
array[id] = []; //array[2] = [] but should be array["2"] = []
```

How do I fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use arrays if you're not going to use int indexers. Just use `Object` for it:

```
var obj = {};
obj[id] = //whatever
```

When you use objects, it will convert the key automatically to string too.